# No debug option for output window in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing

I am trying to see stuff that I'm outputting in a testmethod using Debug.Writeline. However, there is no "Debug" option for my output window. Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Yea, was just making sure it was actually a fix. It was.

Answer (score 1):

I was "Starting without debugging" instead of "Start debugging". That fixed the issue.